# overwriting parameters in Azure Load Testing

Tags: jmeter, parameter-passing, performance-testing, load-testing, azure-load-testing

When the parameters are passed via the 'CSV Data Set Config' in the jmeter script, do we have a way of over-writing the values in Azure Load Testing tool,

I have away of externalising the parameters in Jmeter as well, in azure load testing, but when I combine both the values are not over-written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can overwrite the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). You can overwrite the value of a JMeter Property so if you use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to define some value in the test you can use *user.properties* file to give the property its respective value.

At the same time it would be possible to override the default property value via `-J` command-line argument.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

If you have parameterization implemented via CSV files the only way of amending the values is changing the CSV file itself, in that case you can take a look at [`awk` language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) and/or [`sed` editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/).